# MySQL: JSON column values aggregate into the single JSON object groupped by property

Tags: mysql, sql, json, aggregates

I have a table **variants** with *properties* column type JSON and some data:

| id | product_id | properties(JSON) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | `[{"name": "Color", "value": "Black"}, {"name": "Size", "value": "Xl"}]` |
| 2 | 1 | `[{"name": "Color", "value": "Red"}, {"name": "Size", "value": "Xl"}]` |
| 3 | 1 | `[{"name": "Color", "value": "White"}, {"name": "Size", "value": "L"}]` |
| 4 | 2 | `[{"name": "Type", "value": "Circle"}]` |
| 5 | 2 | `[{"name": "Type", "value": "Box"}]` |
| 6 | 3 | NULL |

I need to get aggregated rows by properties name and *product_id* where each property has an array of unique values. The expected result is:

| product_id | aggregated (JSON) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"Color":["Red", "Black", "White"], "Size": ["XL", "L"]}` |
| 2 | `{"Type": ["Circle", "Box"]}` |

I tried to get *objects* instead of *arrays* but stuck for the next step.

```
SELECT product_id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(jt.name, jt.value) AS json
FROM variants,
     JSON_TABLE(properties, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
         name VARCHAR(1024) PATH '$.name' NULL ON EMPTY,
         value VARCHAR(1024) PATH '$.value' NULL ON EMPTY)
         ) AS jt
GROUP BY id;
```

**Result:**

| product_id | properties(JSON) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"Color": "Black", "Size": "Xl"}` |
| 1 | `{"Color": "Red", "Size": "Xl"}` |
| 1 | `{"Color": "White", "Size: "L"}` |
| 2 | `{"Type": "Circle"}` |
| 2 | `{"Type": "Box"}` |

How can I merge it then?

Comment: Your "aggregation" does not make sense. Your data in variants table is basically product 1 Black XL, product 1 Red XL and product 1 White L. This is not the same as product 1 (Black or Red or White) (XL or L) as indicated by your "aggregation" which suggests 6 variants of product 1.

Comment: @nnichols I want to collect all the unique values of each property. The Next step will be to find missed combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I have to collect values separately from names to aggregate them later into JSON_OBJECT.

```
WITH props_values(product_id, property_name, values_agg) AS (
    SELECT product_id,
           jt.name,
           JSON_KEYS(JSON_OBJECTAGG(jt.value, ''))
    FROM variants,
         JSON_TABLE(
                 properties,
                 '$[*]'
                 COLUMNS (
                     name VARCHAR(1024) PATH '$.name' NULL ON EMPTY,
                     value VARCHAR(1024) PATH '$.value' NULL ON EMPTY
                     )
             ) AS jt
    WHERE jt.name IS NOT NULL
      AND jt.name <> ''
      AND jt.value IS NOT NULL
      AND jt.value <> ''
    GROUP BY product_id, jt.name
)
SELECT product_id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(property_name, values_agg) AS properties_agg
FROM props_values
GROUP BY product_id;
```